# Cloud Composer non interactive authentication

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I've tried a lot before posting this question, I'm not against down votes, at least let me know **WHY** you are down voting.

I have built an Airflow plugin to fetch data from Cloud composer Airflow environment and accessing the cloud composer is working great from browsers as it needs the user to sign in before accessing any of the Airflow endpoints.

In my use case, I need to trigger the endpoints via code. Is there a way in which I can do this.

Below is the Airflow-Flask plugin being used

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import os
import six
import time

from flask import Blueprint, request, Response
from sqlalchemy import or_
from airflow import settings
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException, AirflowConfigException
from airflow.models import DagBag, DagRun
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.utils.dates import date_range as utils_date_range
from airflow.www.app import csrf

airflow_api_blueprint = Blueprint('airflow_api', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v1')


class ApiInputException(Exception):
    pass


class ApiResponse:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    STATUS_OK = 200
    STATUS_BAD_REQUEST = 400
    STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED = 401
    STATUS_NOT_FOUND = 404
    STATUS_SERVER_ERROR = 500

    @staticmethod
    def standard_response(status, payload):
        json_data = json.dumps({
            'response': payload
        })
        resp = Response(json_data, status=status, mimetype='application/json')
        return resp

    @staticmethod
    def success(payload):
        return ApiResponse.standard_response(ApiResponse.STATUS_OK, payload)

    @staticmethod
    def error(status, error):
        return ApiResponse.standard_response(status, {
            'error': error
        })

    @staticmethod
    def bad_request(error):
        return ApiResponse.error(ApiResponse.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST, error)

    @staticmethod
    def not_found(error='Resource not found'):
        return ApiResponse.error(ApiResponse.STATUS_NOT_FOUND, error)

    @staticmethod
    def unauthorized(error='Not authorized to access this resource'):
        return ApiResponse.error(ApiResponse.STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED, error)

    @staticmethod
    def server_error(error='An unexpected problem occurred'):
        return ApiResponse.error(ApiResponse.STATUS_SERVER_ERROR, error)


@airflow_api_blueprint.before_request
def verify_authentication():
    authorization = request.headers.get('authorization')
    try:
        api_auth_key = settings.conf.get('AIRFLOW_API_PLUGIN', 'AIRFLOW_API_AUTH')
    except AirflowConfigException:
        return

    if authorization != api_auth_key:
        return ApiResponse.unauthorized("You are not authorized to use this resource")


def format_dag_run(dag_run):
    return {
        'run_id': dag_run.run_id,
        'dag_id': dag_run.dag_id,
        'state': dag_run.get_state(),
        'start_date': (None if not dag_run.start_date else str(dag_run.start_date)),
        'end_date': (None if not dag_run.end_date else str(dag_run.end_date)),
        'external_trigger': dag_run.external_trigger,
        'execution_date': str(dag_run.execution_date)
    }


def find_dag_runs(session, dag_id, dag_run_id, execution_date):
    qry = session.query(DagRun)
    qry = qry.filter(DagRun.dag_id == dag_id)
    qry = qry.filter(or_(DagRun.run_id == dag_run_id, DagRun.execution_date == execution_date))

    return qry.order_by(DagRun.execution_date).all()


@airflow_api_blueprint.route('/dags', methods=['GET'])
def dags_index():
    dagbag = DagBag()
    dags = []

    for dag_id in dagbag.dags:
        payload = {
            'dag_id': dag_id,
            'full_path': None,
            'is_active': False,
            'last_execution': None,
        }

        dag = dagbag.get_dag(dag_id)

        if dag:
            payload['full_path'] = dag.full_filepath
            payload['is_active'] = (not dag.is_paused)
            payload['last_execution'] = str(dag.latest_execution_date)

        if request.args.get('dag_id') is not None:
            if request.args.get('dag_id') not in payload['dag_id']:
                continue
        dags.append(payload)

    return ApiResponse.success({'dags': dags})


@airflow_api_blueprint.route('/dag_runs', methods=['GET'])
def get_dag_runs():
    dag_runs = []

    session = settings.Session()

    query = session.query(DagRun)

    if request.args.get('state') is not None:
        query = query.filter(DagRun.state == request.args.get('state'))

    if request.args.get('external_trigger') is not None:
        # query = query.filter(DagRun.external_trigger == (request.args.get('external_trigger') is True))
        query = query.filter(DagRun.external_trigger == (request.args.get('external_trigger') in ['true', 'True']))

    if request.args.get('prefix') is not None:
        query = query.filter(DagRun.run_id.ilike('{}%'.format(request.args.get('prefix'))))

    if request.args.get('dag_id') is not None:
        query = query.filter(DagRun.dag_id.ilike('{}%'.format(request.args.get('dag_id'))))

    runs = query.order_by(DagRun.execution_date).all()

    for run in runs:
        dag_runs.append(format_dag_run(run))

    session.close()

    return ApiResponse.success({'dag_runs': dag_runs})


@csrf.exempt
@airflow_api_blueprint.route('/dag_runs', methods=['POST'])
def create_dag_run():
    # decode input
    data = request.get_json(force=True)

    # ensure there is a dag id
    if 'dag_id' not in data or data['dag_id'] is None:
        return ApiResponse.bad_request('Must specify the dag id to create dag runs for')
    dag_id = data['dag_id']

    limit = 500
    partial = False
    if 'limit' in data and data['limit'] is not None:
        try:
            limit = int(data['limit'])
            if limit <= 0:
                return ApiResponse.bad_request('Limit must be a number greater than 0')
            if limit > 500:
                return ApiResponse.bad_request('Limit cannot exceed 500')
        except ValueError:
            return ApiResponse.bad_request('Limit must be an integer')

    if 'partial' in data and data['partial'] in ['true', 'True', True]:
        partial = True

    # ensure there is run data
    start_date = datetime.now()
    end_date = datetime.now()

    if 'start_date' in data and data['start_date'] is not None:
        try:
            start_date = datetime.strptime(data['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        except ValueError:
            error = '\'start_date\' has invalid format \'{}\', Ex format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss'
            return ApiResponse.bad_request(error.format(data['start_date']))

    if 'end_date' in data and data['end_date'] is not None:
        try:
            end_date = datetime.strptime(data['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        except ValueError:
            error = '\'end_date\' has invalid format \'{}\', Ex format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss'
            return ApiResponse.bad_request(error.format(data['end_date']))

    # determine run_id prefix
    prefix = 'manual_{}'.format(int(time.time()))
    if 'prefix' in data and data['prefix'] is not None:
        prefix = data['prefix']

        if 'backfill' in prefix:
            return ApiResponse.bad_request('Prefix cannot contain \'backfill\', Airflow will ignore dag runs using it')
        # ensure prefix doesn't have an underscore appended
        if prefix[:-1:] == "_":
            prefix = prefix[:-1]

    conf = None
    if 'conf' in data and data['conf'] is not None:
        if isinstance(data['conf'], six.string_types):
            conf = data['conf']
        else:
            try:
                conf = json.dumps(data['conf'])
            except Exception:
                return ApiResponse.bad_request('Could not encode specified conf JSON')

    try:
        session = settings.Session()

        dagbag = DagBag('dags')

        if dag_id not in dagbag.dags:
            return ApiResponse.bad_request("Dag id {} not found".format(dag_id))

        dag = dagbag.get_dag(dag_id)

        # ensure run data has all required attributes and that everything is valid, returns transformed data
        runs = utils_date_range(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, delta=dag._schedule_interval)

        if len(runs) > limit and partial is False:
            error = '{} dag runs would be created, which exceeds the limit of {}.' \
                    ' Reduce start/end date to reduce the dag run count'
            return ApiResponse.bad_request(error.format(len(runs), limit))

        payloads = []
        for exec_date in runs:
            run_id = '{}_{}'.format(prefix, exec_date.isoformat())

            if find_dag_runs(session, dag_id, run_id, exec_date):
                continue

            payloads.append({
                'run_id': run_id,
                'execution_date': exec_date,
                'conf': conf
            })

        results = []
        for index, run in enumerate(payloads):
            if len(results) >= limit:
                break

            dag.create_dagrun(
                run_id=run['run_id'],
                execution_date=run['execution_date'],
                state=State.RUNNING,
                conf=conf,
                external_trigger=True
            )
            results.append(run['run_id'])

        session.close()
    except ApiInputException as e:
        return ApiResponse.bad_request(str(e))
    except ValueError as e:
        return ApiResponse.server_error(str(e))
    except AirflowException as e:
        return ApiResponse.server_error(str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        return ApiResponse.server_error(str(e))

    return ApiResponse.success({'dag_run_ids': results})


@airflow_api_blueprint.route('/dag_runs/<dag_run_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_dag_run(dag_run_id):
    session = settings.Session()

    runs = DagRun.find(run_id=dag_run_id, session=session)

    if len(runs) == 0:
        return ApiResponse.not_found('Dag run not found')

    dag_run = runs[0]

    session.close()

    return ApiResponse.success({'dag_run': format_dag_run(dag_run)})
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "trigger the endpoints"? Do you wish to call these methods you've defined on the Composer webserver from a client?

Comment: Yes. I had made plugins in Airflow (non-composer environment which had no authentication in place) and used the plugin end points to fetch information from airflow internal tables. When I'm trying to access the same links from composer from an external client (Where I cannot use web browser) the request fails as the request is not authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

For programmatic auth to Composer's Airflow webserver, you will have to authenticate through IAP.

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf contains a js example of this.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iap/make_iap_request.py is a Python example, but note that it is missing a timeout on the final IAP request (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1812).